# NA to dates with data.table

Tags: r, date, data.table, na, lubridate

I have a data.table

```
require(data.table)
require(lubridate)
testDT <- data.table(dateA = c(NA,NA), dateB = c(ymd("20110101"),ymd("20100101")))
testDT
#       dateA      dateB
#    1:    NA 2011-01-01
#    2:    NA 2010-01-01
```

I would like to do the following operation: if dateA is NA, then use the same value as in dateB. I've tried the following command:

```
> testDT[is.na(dateA), dateA := dateB]
Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(testDT, is.na(dateA), `:=`(dateA, dateB)) :
  Coerced 'double' RHS to 'logical' to match the column's type; may have truncated precision. Either change the target column ['dateA'] to 'double' first (by creating a new 'double' vector length 2 (nrows of entire table) and assign that; i.e. 'replace' column), or coerce RHS to 'logical' (e.g. 1L, NA_[real|integer]_, as.*, etc) to make your intent clear and for speed. Or, set the column type correctly up front when you create the table and stick to it, please.
```

As you can see, there was a warning and the result is weird:

```
> testDT
   dateA      dateB
1:  TRUE 2011-01-01
2:  TRUE 2010-01-01
```

Why doesn't it work?

P.S. I know we can use:

```
> testDT[,dateA := ifelse(is.na(dateA), dateB, dateA)]
> testDT
   dateA      dateB
1: 14975 2011-01-01
2: 14610 2010-01-01
> testDT[,dateA := as.Date(dateA, origin = "1970-01-01")]
> testDT
        dateA      dateB
1: 2011-01-01 2011-01-01
2: 2010-01-01 2010-01-01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that warning message because the `dateA`-column doesn't have the right class (as already mentioned by @Emmanuel-Lin):

> ```
> > str(testDT)
> Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  2 variables:
>  $ dateA: logi  NA NA
>  $ dateB: Date, format: "2011-01-01" "2010-01-01"
>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
> ```

A possible solution is to convert the `dateA`-column to a date class first with either `as.Date` or the build-in date functions of [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
# convert 'dateA'-column to 'Date'- class first
testDT[, dateA := as.Date(dateA)]   # alternatively: as.IDate(dateA)

# fill the 'NA' values in the 'dateA'-column
testDT[is.na(dateA), dateA := dateB][]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > testDT
>         dateA      dateB
> 1: 2011-01-01 2011-01-01
> 2: 2010-01-01 2010-01-01
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have NAs in first column, it guesses it is Logical.

If you add one elemnt that isn't NA, it works perfectly:

Your example with one more element

```
require(data.table)
require(lubridate)
testDT <- data.table(dateA = c(NA,NA, ymd("20110101")), dateB = c(ymd("20110101"),ymd("20100101"), ymd("20100101")))

testDT[is.na(dateA), dateA := dateB]
```

The result:

```
> testDT
   dateA      dateB
1: 14975 2011-01-01
2: 14610 2010-01-01
3: 14975 2010-01-01
```

So why do you have only NAs?

Comment: Nit pick: "Since you only have NAs in first column, *it guesses the type as logical*".